# Replace the last child of a parent with JS

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with a function:

```js
function compareSoundclips(e) {
    if (e.target.id !== "output-compare-2") return;

    // Grab the wrapper
    const wrapper = document.querySelector("#iframe-container");

    // Add grid class
    if (!wrapper.classList.contains("grid-2")) {
        wrapper.classList.add("grid-2");
    }

    const div = document.createElement("div");
    // Create the sound clip
    div.innerHTML = `
<iframe
    width="100%"
    height="400"
    scrolling="yes"
    frameborder="no"
    style="height: 400px;"
    src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/${e.target.value}&color=%23ad9462&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=false&show_user=false&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false">
</iframe>
`;

    wrapper.append(div);

    if (wrapper.childElementCount > 2) {
        wrapper.replaceChild(div, wrapper.lastElementChild);
    }
}
```

Essentially, I have a wrapper (`#iframe-container`) that has an iframe already in it that I want to keep. I'm using this function to create a new div with the new iframe in it.

On change, I want to only keep two iframes total, and replace the last with the new one.

The problem I'm having is that it keeps adding divs - where am I going wrong?

Edit: a `change` event listener triggers this function on a selectbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always appending, and then sometimes replacing the thing you just appended... with the thing you just appended

```
wrapper.append(div); // wrapper.lastElementChild is now div

if (wrapper.childElementCount > 2) {
    wrapper.replaceChild(div, wrapper.lastElementChild);
}
```

Should be

```
if (wrapper.childElementCount > 2) {
    wrapper.replaceChild(div, wrapper.lastElementChild);
} else {
    wrapper.append(div);
}
```

Comment: Got it working by changing `(wrapper.childElementCount >= 2)`. Thanks!